# How to get data from table cell?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsp

In my webpage i have a table. In each cell of table it contain a textbox with some data which can be editable.all text boxes id and name are same. how can i access a pirticular cell's textbox data?

Comment: _all text boxes id *** are same_ __Identifiers in HTML must be unique__

Comment: can't we get the value through row coloumn index of the table?

Comment: _Yes_ we can but you need to show the HTML

Comment: use same class and use `:eq()` or `eq()` , eg : `$('.table tr:eq(0) td:eq(0)')` , to get first first cell

Answer (score 1):

```
$("tr:eq("+a+") td:eq("+b+")")...
```

`a` is the row index starting from **0**, while `b` is the column index starting from **0**

Using jquery like this, you may access the td elements using row index and column index.

To submit all data in td to the server, use the following code:

In javascript:

```
var a = {h:[]};
for (var c=0;c<$("tr").length;c++){
    for (var o = 0;o<$("tr:eq("+c+") td").length;o++){
        a["h"][c][o]=$("tr:eq("+c+") td:eq("+o+")").html(); // your value
    }
}
$.post("http://example.com/submit",$.param(a));
```

In PHP:

```
$p = $_POST["h"];
$p[$a][$b] // $a is the row number from 0, $b is the column number from 0
```

Comment: i have a table in my webpage. the table tag is with in a form tag.That form has a action to redirect to some page. i need to upload the table data into database when submit button is pressed.so is the possible to access table data in server by using table row column index?